# Reuse same DOM element in two different react components

Tags: reactjs

I have a small question.

Let's imagine I have component A which holds , after component A does it's job I render component B. I would like that same DOM element (textarea) would be reused in component B.
The reason is if new textarea is rendered in component B it loses focus as it's just new DOM element. It's like after component A lifetame take textarea element from it and just put it in component B instead of rendering new one.

Sample APP
https://jsfiddle.net/remdex/v67gqyLa/1/#&togetherjs=aiRvTGhRK2

```js
class AComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return ( <textarea>A Component</textarea>  )
 }
}

class BComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return ( <textarea>Should be A Component text</textarea>  )
 }
}

class ABComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {'component' : 'A'};
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div><button onClick={(e) => this.setState({component:'B'})}>Switch to B Component</button>
      {this.state.component == 'A' && <AComponent/>}
      {this.state.component == 'B' && <BComponent/>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ABComponent />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: You can keep A mounted and render B, right? What have you tried? Please update question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Added sample. Basically I want that textarea DOM instance would be the same just in another component so I would not lose a focus...

Comment: Is your issue only the focus or do you want to preserve its content as well?

Comment: I want to preserve it's content also... Just move textarea from component A to another component B without creating a new DOM element in component B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sandbox example, **ComponentA** and **ComponentB** are redundant. You can create **ComponentA** and **ComponentB** as a `class` if they are using same element and operate them with **ComponentAB**. You can change your **ComponentAB** like:

```js
class A {
  handle(input) { 
    // Do your A job here and return result
    console.log("Handler A is running");
  };
}

class B {
  handle(input) {
    // Do your B job here and return result
    console.log("Handler B is running");
  };
}

class ABComponent extends React.Component {
  currentHandler = new A();

  handleClick = () => {
   this.currentHandler = new B();
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    // Handle the input with current handler
    var result = this.currentHandler.handle(event.target.value);
    // If you want you can use result to cahnge something in view
    // this.setState({value: result});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
              Switch to B Component
          </button>
          <textarea onChange={this.handleChange}>Text Area used between A class and B class</textarea>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I also edit the codebox example. You can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/481vjude/9/).

Comment: And that's exactly a problem. Components are to different just to have textarea in a parent component... That's why i was looking for solution just to take part of mounted component and put it in another component once time comes...

Comment: You can not move an element inside the mounted component to another sorry. The best solution is to have a parent component that holds the element that you do not want it to be mounted again and again.

Comment: Just thought perhaps it's somehow possible to define textarea component in parent as variable and just pass it component A first and then to component B so always only in one place it would be rendered and react would not have to make new dom element each time...

Comment: When an element is mounted on component A, you can pass it to component B if component A is still mounted. But it is a workaround and not reliable. But if you unmount component A, the element inside component A will be unmounted too. It is not a recommend thing to pass elements between components at the same hierarchical level. You need to use a parent or change focus and content of the new element according to old one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a `ref`. `ABComponent` passes a ref to `BComponent` to attach to the `textarea`. When the state of `ABComponent` updates to `component = 'B'`, then the ref is used to set focus. Use a ref passed to `AComponent` to grab its textarea value before it's unmounted, then set the value of the textarea in B to it.

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

...

class AComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { textareaRef } = this.props;
    return <textarea ref={textareaRef} defaultValue="A Component" />;
  }
}

class BComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { textareaRef } = this.props;
    return <textarea ref={textareaRef} defaultValue="Should be A Component text" />;
  }
}

class ABComponent extends Component {
  state = { component: "A" };
  refA = createRef();
  refB = createRef();

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { component, content } = this.state;
    if (prevState.component !== component) {
      if (component === "B") {
        this.refB.current.focus();
        this.refB.current.value = content;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={e =>
            this.setState({ component: "B", content: this.refA.current.value })
          }
        >
          Switch to B Component
        </button>
        {this.state.component === "A" && <AComponent textareaRef={this.refA} />}
        {this.state.component === "B" && <BComponent textareaRef={this.refB} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit set focus on new text area]

Comment: That you can focus B component once it's mounted I know. But it's still new DOM  element in component B... I need that DOM element from component A be moved to component B...

Comment: @Remdex You can't just move a component, but you *can* move its content. Check updated answer.